# Why i can write a object like "c = { get a(){} }"?

Tags: javascript

When I wrote

```
var c = { get a(){} };
```

The result is the c object has a "get a" and "set a" property.

Why?

Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Why not? That's how the language was designed. This is the syntax to specify getter and setter properties in an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sometimes it is desirable to allow access to a property that returns a
>   dynamically computed value, or you may want reflect the status of an
>   internal variable without requiring the use of explicit method calls.
>   In JavaScript, this can be accomplished with the use of a getter. It
>   is not possible to simultaneously have a getter bound to a property
>   and have that property actually hold a value, although it is possible
>   to use a getter and a setter in conjunction to create a type of
>   pseudo-property.

— https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get